# ¿Como agregar datos a una TableLayout por medio de un Scaner?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

Soy nuevo en el desarrollo de aplicaciones Android estoy tratando de agregar datos a una tabla por medio de un Scaner, el problema es que cuando inicio el scaner este lee el código de barras pero no puedo agregar ese valor a mi tabla.
No obstante si agrego datos sin abrir el scaner mi tabla trabaja perfectamente tengo el siguiente código, alguien me podría apoyar. Gracias.

Del lado del diseño tengo lo siguiente:

*1- TextView
*2- EditText
*2- Botones
*1- TableLayout

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/scan_format"
        android:hint="muestra datos del codigo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textIsSelectable="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_below="@id/scan_button" />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="DATO1" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/txtlastname"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:text="DATO2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/scan_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:onClick="Escanear"
        android:text="ABRIR ESCANER" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="AGREGAR DATOS A LA TABLA" />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <HorizontalScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TableLayout
                android:id="@+id/table"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </TableLayout>
        </HorizontalScrollView>
    </ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

En mi Activity Main tengo el siguiente codigo.

```
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

 Button scanBtn;
 TextView formatTxt, contentTxt;
 ZXingScannerView vistaescaner;


 TableLayout tableLayout;
 EditText txtName, txtLastName;
 Button btn1;
 String[]header={"Id","Nombre","Apellido"};
 ArrayList<String[]> rows = new ArrayList<>();
 TableDynamic tableDynamic;
 String _a,_b;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    tableLayout=(TableLayout)findViewById(R.id.table);
    txtName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtname);
    txtLastName=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtlastname);
    btn1=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button);


    tableDynamic = new TableDynamic(tableLayout,getApplicationContext());
    tableDynamic.addHeader(header);
    tableDynamic.addData(getClients());
    tableDynamic.backgroundHeader(Color.BLUE);
    tableDynamic.backgroundData(Color.parseColor("#58D3F7"),Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.lineColor(Color.BLACK);
    tableDynamic.textColorhHeader(Color.WHITE);
    tableDynamic.textColorData(Color.parseColor("#000000"));

    contentTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);

    btn1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            _a=txtName.getText().toString();
            _b=txtLastName.getText().toString();
            String[] item = new String[]{"2",_a,_b};
            tableDynamic.addItems(item);

        }
    });


}
public ArrayList<String[]> getClients() {
    rows.add(new String[]{"PRUEBA", "DE", "QUE LLENA"});
    //rows.add(new String[]{"2","b","Lopez"});

    return rows;
}

public void Escanear(View view){
    vistaescaner = new ZXingScannerView(MainActivity.this);
    vistaescaner.setResultHandler(new zxingscanner());
    setContentView(vistaescaner);
    vistaescaner.startCamera();
}


public class  zxingscanner implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result) {
        String dato = result.getText();
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        vistaescaner.stopCamera();
        formatTxt = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.scan_format);
        formatTxt.setText(dato);
        String s = dato;
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s, ",");
        dato = st.nextToken();
        String[] item = new String[]{dato,"prueba","pruebaa"};
        tableDynamic.addItems(item);
    }
}
}
```

Y cuento con una clase llamada TablDinamic encargada del llenado de la tabla.

```
public class TableDynamic {
private TableLayout tableLayout;
private Context context;
private String[]header;
private ArrayList<String[]>data;
private TableRow tableRow;
private TextView txtCell;
private int indexC;
private int indexR;
private boolean multicolor=false;
int firstColor, secondColor,textColor;


public TableDynamic(TableLayout tableLayout, Context context){
    this.tableLayout=tableLayout;
    this.context=context;
}
public void addHeader(String[]header){
    this.header=header;
    createHeader();

}

public void addData(ArrayList<String[]>data){
    this.data=data;
    createDataTable();
}

private void newRow(){
    tableRow=new TableRow(context);
}
private void newCell(){
    txtCell= new TextView(context);
    txtCell.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    txtCell.setTextSize(25);
}
private void createHeader(){
    indexC=0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC<header.length){
        newCell();
        txtCell.setText(header[indexC++]);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
}
private void createDataTable(){
    String info;
    for(indexR=1;indexR<=data.size();indexR++){
        newRow();
        for(indexC=0;indexC<header.length;indexC++){
            newCell();
            String[] row = data.get(indexR-1);
            info=(indexC<row.length)?row[indexC]:"";
            txtCell.setText(info);
            tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());
        }

        tableLayout.addView(tableRow);
    }
}

public void addItems(String[]Item){
    String info;
    data.add(Item);
    indexC=0;
    newRow();
    while (indexC<header.length){
        newCell();
        info=(indexC<Item.length)?Item[indexC++]:"";
        txtCell.setText(info);
        tableRow.addView(txtCell,newTableRowParams());
    }
    tableLayout.addView(tableRow,data.size());
    reColor();
}

public void backgroundHeader(int color){
        indexC=0;
        while (indexC<header.length){
            txtCell=getCell(0,indexC++);
            txtCell.setBackgroundColor(color);
        }
}

public void backgroundData(int firstColor, int secondColor){
    for(indexR=1;indexR<=data.size();indexR++){
        multicolor=!multicolor;
        for(indexC=0;indexC<header.length;indexC++){
            txtCell=getCell(indexR,indexC);
            txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multicolor)?firstColor:secondColor);
        }
    }
    this.firstColor=firstColor;
    this.secondColor=secondColor;
}

public  void lineColor(int color){
    indexR=0;
    while(indexR<data.size()){
        getRow(indexR++).setBackgroundColor(color);
    }
}

public void textColorData(int color){
    for(indexR=1;indexR<=data.size();indexR++)
        for(indexC=0;indexC<header.length;indexC++)
            getCell(indexR,indexC).setTextColor(color);

    this.textColor=color;
}

public void textColorhHeader(int color){
    indexC=0;
    while(indexC<header.length){
        getCell(0,indexC++).setTextColor(color);
    }
}

private void reColor(){
    indexC=0;
    multicolor=!multicolor;
    while (indexC<header.length){
        txtCell=getCell(data.size(),indexC++);
        txtCell.setBackgroundColor((multicolor)?firstColor:secondColor);
        txtCell.setTextColor(textColor);
    }
}

private TableRow getRow(int index){
    return (TableRow)tableLayout.getChildAt(index);
}

private TextView getCell(int rowindex, int columindex){
    tableRow=getRow(rowindex);
    return (TextView) tableRow.getChildAt(columindex);
}

private TableRow.LayoutParams newTableRowParams(){
    TableRow.LayoutParams params= new TableRow.LayoutParams();
    params.setMargins(1,1,1,1);
    params.weight=1;
    return params;
}
}
```

Y en mi Build Gradle cuento con la siguiente dependencia para el scaner

```
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9.8'
```

Comment: primero proba con table.requestLayout(); despues de hacerle el addView(), ademas revisa que el handleResult del ZXingScanner este ejecutando en el thread principal.